# Replace hex in binary file with shell without sed

Tags: scripts, sed, sh

I have binary file that I want to replace with shell script `0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd` with `0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44`

I can get `0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd` into shell script like `$1` but how  can I replace it with `0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44` without sed?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to clarify your requirements.  For example, `sed` is a standard part of Ubuntu and, for that matter, all POSIX systems.  How is it that you have an Ubuntu system that doesn't have `sed`?   Answering that question might help us understand what tools you do have available.

Comment: Perhaps it's a requirement of the script and not that OPs lacks the sed tool!

Comment: Probably `tr` is more appropriate than (line-base) `sed` anyhow - another option would be `perl` (which has its own `tr` and may be invoked in "slurp mode")

Comment: Use `dd` command. [link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146922/is-dd-able-to-overwrite-parts-of-a-file)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290816/how-to-overwrite-some-bytes-of-a-binary-file-with-dd)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps bash indexed arrays would help:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

my_hex=(0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd)
my_new_hex=(0x11 0x22 0x33 0x44)

# exchange values
for i in $(seq 1 "${#my_hex[@]}")
do
        my_hex["$i" - 1]=${my_new_hex[$i - 1]}
        echo "${my_hex[$i - 1]}"
done
```

Comment: Suggestion for improvement: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays